# Unable to convert Json string to Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to convert my json into a map uisng jackson-core-2.9.6 . My json is

```
 {
  "name": "Loren",
  "inputDetails": {
  "truncated": false,
   "result": [
     {
    "subjects": [
      {
        "math": "50",
        "SST": "37 ",
        "status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
},
"timeoutInSeconds": null
}
```

and the Java Code is by which I am trying to parse this JSON into Map is like this

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    
    String request="{\r\n  \"name\": \"Loren\",\r\n  \"inputDetails\": {\r\n    \"truncated\": false,\r\n    \"result\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"subjects\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"math\": \"50\",\r\n            \"SST\": \"37 \",\r\n            \"status\": \"ACTIVE\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  },\r\n  \"timeoutInSeconds\": null\r\n}";
    try {  
            List servicesResponse = null;
            Map<String,Object> inputParam=null;
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            request =  objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);
            objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
            objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
            inputParam = (Map<String, Object>) objectMapper.readValue(request, Map.class);
            servicesResponse = (List)inputParam.get("result");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
  }
```

Exception which I am getting is
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{
"name": "Loren",
"inputDetails": {
"truncated": false,
"result": [
{
"subjects": [
{
"math": "50",
"SST": "37 ",
"status": "ACTIVE"
}
]
}
]
},
"timeoutInSeconds": null
}')
at [Source: (String)""{\r\n  "name": "Loren",\r\n  "inputDetails": {\r\n    "truncated": false,\r\n    "result": [\r\n      {\r\n        "subjects": [\r\n          {\r\n            "math": "50",\r\n            "SST": "37 ",\r\n            "status": "ACTIVE"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  },\r\n  "timeoutInSeconds": null\r\n}""; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1342)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1031)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:357)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
at Test.main(Test.java:22)

I have tried looking into similar questions available on Stakoverflow but unable to find json with similar structure which is having both string and objects.

Comment: please provide more details, this code runs perfect for me

Comment: @DanielTaub I have added full code of mine- com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{
  "name": "Loren",
  "inputDetails": {
    "truncated": false,
    "result": [
      {
        "subjects": [
          {
            "math": "50",
            "SST": "37 ",
            "status": "ACTIVE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what causing your problem

```
request = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);
```

It affects your String json, just pass the String object to the `readValue` method, it accepts also strings

Answer (score 1):

The above code worked for me for parsing. But since you need result variable, it is inside `inputDetails`. So you need to change last line as below:

```
List servicesResponse = (List) ((Map<String, Object>)inputParam.get("inputDetails")).get("result");
```

Comment: I am not able to parse it only. I have added my full code , with exception I am getting.